# Trouble with a MySQL-Query

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to execute this query I got trouble.

```
INSERT INTO af_pres (cod,pres,fecha,tipo,stad,oper,ref,monto)
 VALUES 
 ("",
      (CASE
        (SELECT p.pres FROM af_pres p WHERE 
         p.pres LIKE "%0100000100191000140100%" AND 
         p.fecha LIKE "%2014%" = '' 
      THEN pres ELSE 
        (pres = "2014"))END),
       "2014-09-26","G","1","M","MOD-2014",70000);
```

Comment: Please clarify "trouble"

Comment: I'm not surprised. The syntax is just... erm, random. Which makes sense, given your nickname :)

Comment: My goodness, this query is all over the place....  What are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use SELECT in CASE as you are doing in your query. MySQL does not have this feature built in.
If you describe what you want to do, we can help you more.

Ok here is a solution, but I have not tried it :)

```
INSERT INTO af_pres (cod,pres,fecha,tipo,stad,oper,ref,monto)
VALUES 
    ("", 
    (SELECT IF (COUNT(p.pres) > 0, pres, '2014') 
     FROM af_pres p 
     WHERE p.pres LIKE "%0100000100191000140100%" 
     AND p.fecha LIKE "%2014%" = ''), 
    "2014-09-26",
    "G",
    "1",
    "M",
    "MOD-2014",
    70000);
```